# Does Dictionary.Keys.List()[i] correspond to Dictionary.Values.ToList()[i]?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` data type. My question is, is `Dictionary.Keys.ToList()[i]` always correspond to `Dictionary.Values.ToList()[i]` ? That is, will the following test always passes

```
public void DictionaryTest(int i, Dictionary<U,T> dict)
{
  var key = dict.Keys.ToList()[i];
  Assert.AreEqual(dict[key], dict.Values.ToList()[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the MSDN entry for [Dictionary.Keys Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx):

> The order of the keys in the Dictionary.KeyCollection is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the Dictionary.ValueCollection returned by the Values property.

Comment: Is it correct to say SortedDictionary have specified order on keys?

Comment: @RayCheng The documentation I quoted refers to the `Dictionary` class. To answer your question, you need to check the documentation for `SortedDictionary.Keys`, which says "The keys in the `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` are sorted according to the `Comparer` property and are in the same order as the associated values in the `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` returned by the `Values` property." So the answer to your question is *yes*.

Answer (score 6):

I would say yes based on this from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx):

> The order of the values in the Dictionary.ValueCollection is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the Dictionary.KeyCollection returned by the Keys property.

Answer (score 0):

In your code - yes.
But if you override GetHashCode() into U Class and then made some changes that will change value of GetHashCode() and invoke Assert, it's possible that it will be false, cause Dictionary is implemented as a hash table. The next code returns false:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<A, int> d = new Dictionary<A, int>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                d.Add(new A { Hash = i}, i);
            }
            DictionaryTest(5, d);
        }

        public static void DictionaryTest(int i, Dictionary<A, int> dict)
        {
            A key = dict.Keys.ToList()[i];
            key.Hash = 4;
            Console.WriteLine(dict[key].Equals(dict.Values.ToList()[i]));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public int Hash { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return this.GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode();
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Hash;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you violate the contract of `Dictionary` you get undefined behavior. Surprise surprise. "As long as an object is used as a key in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value."

Comment: It will not be false, because order of entries will be other, but same again.

Comment: But it's possible and some people made this mistake. They override GetHashCode() method and use objects with Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Reflector says, that in Framework 2.0 - 4.0 both KeyCollection and ValueCollection are enumerating over dictionary.entries collection. That's why order will be the same.
And by the way same order will be for enumerating over dictionary itself (KeyValuePairs).

Comment: It's important that not just the current implementation does it, but that the contract of `Keys` and `Values` guarantees it. Else it might exhibit different behavior in future versions or different implementations.

Comment: Well, specification could change in future versions too. I just told how it implemented now and why order is the samw.